# Cannot read Decimal values while reading file shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file in Unix which have lines like:

```
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850848.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY].
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850851.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY1].
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850852.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY10].
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850860.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY11].
```

while reading file in .sh file, echo prints like

```
INFO 29-4-2015 20:22:56 NOD_VMT01-32 DIRECTOR VAR_27028 Use override value 0 for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY9].
```

`[850852.000000000000000]`  becomes `0`.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do  
if [[ $line == *"Use override value"* ]]
then
    echo $line 
    SUBSTRING=`echo $line| cut -d '[' -f 3 | cut -d ']' -f 1`
    SUBSTRING1=`echo $line| cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1`
    echo $SUBSTRING" = "$SUBSTRING1
fi
done < $1
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you share your exact command? It is not clear what you mean

Comment: Specifically how are you reading the data, what are you doing with it, and how are you echoing it.

Comment: while read line
do 
echo $line 
if [[ $line == *"Use override value"* ]]
then
 echo $line 
 SUBSTRING=`echo $line| cut -d '[' -f 3 | cut -d ']' -f 1`
 SUBSTRING1=`echo $line| cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1`
 echo $SUBSTRING" = "$SUBSTRING1
fi
#array12=($(grep -e "Use override value" . $line | cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1))
#array11=($(grep -e "Use override value" . $line | cut -d '[' -f 3 | cut -d ']' -f 1))
#for ((i=0;i<${#array11[@]};++i)); do
# echo ${array11[$i]} " = " ${array12[$i]};
#done

done < $1

Comment: Don't put your script in a comment. Edit your original question and paste the script in. Make sure to indent each line with an extra four spaces so stackoverflow will display it correctly.

Comment: I have to extract values within square brackets like [$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY]=[850848.000000000000000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are failing to quote your `"$variables"`:

```
while read line; do   
    if [[ $line == *"Use override value"* ]]; then     
        echo "$line"
        sub1=$(cut -d '[' -f 3 <<< "$line" | cut -d ']' -f 1)
        sub2=$(cut -d '[' -f 2 <<< "$line" | cut -d ']' -f 1)    
        echo "$sub1 = $sub2"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

```
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850848.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY].
$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY = 850848.000000000000000
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850851.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY1].
$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY1 = 850851.000000000000000
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850852.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY10].
$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY10 = 850852.000000000000000
INFO    29-4-2015 20:22:56  NOD_VMT01-32    DIRECTOR    VAR_27028   Use override value [850860.000000000000000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY11].
$$mplt_PROCESS_KEY11 = 850860.000000000000000
```

What happens if you `echo  [850860.000000000000000]` at a shell prompt?
Do you have a file named "0" in  your current directory?

Comment: Yes, There is file in current directory with name "0" and when i echo  [850860.000000000000000] at shell prompt it returns 0. Can you please help?